# How to Ignore wildcards in the range.find function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Is it possible to treat wildcards as normal chars in the range.find function.

I am searching through a list for string matches, but am running into issues, as some of the strings contain wild cards.
Example:

List:
ab
cde
fghi
jk
?l

```
r = list.range.find(s, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

if **s** = "??" this would result in **r** equalling "ab"
Where as I want "??" to be treated like a normal string that would only match a string of "??"
If **s** = "?l" I would want **r** to equal "?l" not "ab"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `~`, i.e `~?`.

For your `?l`, it is `~?l`.

General solution:

```
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(s, "?", "~?")
```

Comment: I do not know what will be in **s**, so will not know if there are wildcards in there

Comment: @RisingCascade, what do you want to match?

Comment: @RisingCascade, sorry for the mistake before. --b

Comment: Figured it out am using  "s = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(s, "?", "~?")
    s = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(s, "#", "~#")
    s = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(s, "*", "~*")" to ignore the wildcards before the find function

Comment: @RisingCascade, just use `substitute`. I have tested it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that has sorted out the search function

Comment: You should consider using the VBA.Replace function instead.